# Problem with jQuery.before().remove

Tags: jquery

All
what's the problem this ..

```
jQuery(function() {
    var $tooltip = jQuery('<div class="tooltip">You can mention..?</div>');
    jQuery('.link-class:first').live("hover", function() {
        jQuery(this).before($tooltip);
    },
    function() {
        jQuery(this).before($tooltip).remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is this is what you want:

```
jQuery(this).prev('.tooltip').remove();
```

http://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: but i need to remove this $tooltip

Comment: The above should do just that. Did you try it? `.before` will  put the tooltip div before `.link-class:first`. `.prev` will select it.

Comment: @user631915 - what do you mean by 'this $tooltip' ?